# How to reduce the fraction with my own Fraction class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I recently started coding and was trying to make a fraction class on my own!

I've been stuck with reducing the fraction for hours!  I need to use
"def reduction(self)", with self as the parameter, but I only know how to use this function without (self)! How can I reduce the fraction
with self as a parameter for my reduction function?

Can people please help me out? Here is my code...

```
class MyFraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator: int, denominator: int):
        self.numerator = numerator
        self.denominator = denominator

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.numerator) + "/" + str(self.denominator)

    def negate(self):
        return MyFraction(-1*self.numerator, self.denominator)

    def inverse(self):
        return MyFraction(self.denominator, self.numerator)

    def reduction(self):
        for i in range(self.denominator-1, 0, -1):
            if self.denominator % i == 0 and self.numerator % i == 0:
                return i
            else:
                return 1
        self.numerator //= i
        self.denominator //= i
        return MyFraction(self.numerator, self.denominator)


    def __add__(self, frac):
        new_num = (self.numerator * frac.denominator) + \
            (self.denominator * frac.numerator)
        new_den = self.denominator*frac.denominator
        return MyFraction(new_num, new_den)

    def __sub__(self, frac):
        new_num = (self.numerator * frac.denominator) - \
            (self.denominator * frac.numerator)
        new_den = self.denominator * frac.denominator
        return MyFraction(new_num, new_den)

    def __mul__(self, frac):
        new_num = self.numerator * frac.numerator
        new_den = self.denominator * frac.denominator
        return MyFraction(new_num, new_den)

    def __truediv__(self, frac):
        new_num = self.denominator * frac.numerator
        new_den = self.numerator * frac.denominator
        return MyFraction(new_num, new_den)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = MyFraction(1, 2)
    b = MyFraction(13, 15)
    x = a + b
    print(f'x={x}, a={a}, b={b}')

    c = x - a  # 18/15
    d = x - 1
    y = c / d  # 36/11
    print(f'y={y}, c={c}, d={d}')
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to use the reduction through `y.reduction()`? What's not working?

Comment: To leave the `for` loop use `break` (not `return`). Also, there are much better algortihms, see GCD: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor